# MVC5 SPA IdentityUser add State and display it as Dropdown with static values

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, single-page-application

I am trying to add a state field to the user registration on the default MVC SPA template. I want to use a dropdown that doesn't link to a database field, or anyother crazy stuff other than having them statically/manually created as they are not going to change.

Is there any easy to implement solution or a way that I can implement this easily without altering the defaults too much?

Comment: just add the markup for the select element wherever needed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound lazy ;-). This should do the job:

Add this property to the RegisterViewModel in the AccountViewModel.cs:

```
[Display(Name = "State")]
public string State { get; set; }
```

This will take take of posting the state value. Then add this to the Register.cshtml, below the *confirm password* field:

```
@{  var states = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Example 1", Value="Example1" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Example 2", Value="Example2" }
    };
}
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, states, "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Sorry that you consider it lazy, I am new to using MVC, only used WebApi before, really appreciate the help and it works as asked. Thanks a lot @kloanrubeek

Comment: No problem, I was kidding you ;-)